# C++ object pool that returns a smart pointer on request

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
template<typename T>
class object_pool {

public:
  explicit object_pool(std::size_t initial_size = 1048u);

  object_pool(const object_pool&) = delete;

  object_pool(object_pool&&) = delete;

  ~object_pool();

  object_pool& operator=(const object_pool&) = delete;
  object_pool& operator=(object_pool&&) = delete;

  template<typename... Args>
  std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>> request(Args&&... args);

private:
  std::deque<T*> _object_pool; // is deque the best container?

};

template<typename T>
object_pool<T>::object_pool(std::size_t initial_size) : _object_pool() {
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < initial_size; ++i) {
    T* object = reinterpret_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T)));
    _object_pool.push_back(object);
  }
}

template<typename T>
object_pool<T>::~object_pool() {
  while (!_object_pool.empty()) {
    T* object = _object_pool.front();
    _object_pool.pop_front();
    ::operator delete(object);
  }
}

template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>> object_pool<T>::request(Args&&... args) {
  T* object = nullptr;

  if (!_object_pool.empty()) {
    object = new(_object_pool.front()) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    _object_pool.pop_front();
  } else {
    object = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  auto object_pointer = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>(object, [this](T* object){ 
    object->~T();
    _object_pool.push_back(object);
  });

  return object_pointer;
}
```

My goal is to write a very lightweight object pool for another project.
The `_object_pool` is supposed to just hold raw *uninitialized* pointers to `T`, which I then initialize when an object is requested. Likewise, i call the destructor on the returned instances before putting them back into the `_object_pool` so that resources used by them can be freed.
I am also allocating space for a set ammount of instances when I create the pool and only request new memory when all object from the `_object_pool` are in use.

Comment: If you have unit tests for this code it would help us review the code if they were posted as well.

Answer (score 1):

**unique_ptr ownership / lifetime issues**:

Normally, `std::unique_ptr` indicates single ownership of an object and thus gives the user certain expectations of how they can safely use it. But here the `object_pool` "owns" the object (or at least the underlying memory), so the use of `unique_ptr` is rather misleading. Consider the following code:

```
{
    auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>>();

    {
        object_pool<int> pool;
        ptr = pool.request(5);
    }

    // uh oh...
}
```

We would normally expect the above code to work without problems. However, the custom `unique_ptr` deleter will attempt to call `_object_pool.push_back(object)` on a pool that doesn't exist any more.

At the very least, I'd suggest "hiding" the use of `unique_ptr` behind a typedef, and documenting thoroughly that it *must* go out of scope before the object pool:

```
template<class T>
using object_pool_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>;
```

This also means the user doesn't have to worry about typing out the custom deleter signature.

It would be even better to make `object_pool_ptr` a wrapper class around the `unique_ptr` to hide it completely.

---

**object_pool destructor**:

As a debugging feature, the `object_pool` could keep track of the total number of objects allocated. We could then check that our "free list" (the `_object_pool` deque) is the correct size in the `object_pool` destructor, rather than waiting until a pointer goes out of scope.

I don't think it's necessary to call `pop_front()` on individual elements in the destructor. We could call `clear()` after the loop, or allow the `_object_pool` to clean up naturally in its own destructor.

---

[Note: below this point are just possible things that might be useful, depending on what other features your object pool needs, and what you're actually using it for].

---

**tracking allocated memory inside the pool**:

This "object pool is a free-list" strategy is really clever... but maybe there are advantages to keeping track of all the allocated memory inside the object pool too?

We could use a `std::deque<std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T)>>` member variable allowing us to call `push_back` to add more elements without invalidating references (and hence pointers) to the original elements.

This also means we avoid the need to call global operators `new` and `delete` for every element.

---

**manual lifetime (but not memory) management**:

If the object pool keeps track of all allocated memory as above, perhaps it's ok to give the user a simple raw pointer to an allocated object and expect them to call an `object_pool.destroy(ptr);` function when they're done with it?

This isn't dangerous in terms of object lifetimes, since the object pool can still call the object destructors when necessary (and maybe issue a warning or `assert()` if desired). Although it would open up the possibility of pointers to destroyed objects being accidentally reused.

It also allows us to make the `object_pool` moveable, and add a `clear()` function.

---